# Maximum number of elements, where no two are in relation

Tags: elementary-set-theory, graph-theory, relations

I have a set S.
I have reflexive, symmetric and non-transitive relation R on SxS.

I have to find size of set P, which is the biggest subset of S where :

Any two distinct elements of P are not in relation R.

Any idea how to solve this in better way then brute-forcing? 
I think, I can put elements of S into graph and use some kind of graph algorithm, but I am completely lost here.
Notice, I only need size of P, not elements of P.

Comment: Is "non-transitive" a restrictive condition, or do you just mean that $R$ is not guaranteed to be transitive?

Comment: its restrictive condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $(S,R)$ already *is* an undirected graph, with $S$ being the set of vertices and $R$ the edges, if you decide to ignore the self-loops that ariese from $R$ being reflexive.

What you're looking for is a maximal *clique* in the *complementary* graph $(S,(S\times S) \setminus R)$. Finding even the size of a maximal clique is a well known [NP-complete problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_problem), so you shouldn't hope to find an algorithm that's significantly better than brute force.